# Can't delete OpenVPN on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn

OpenVPN still responds my commands even after I deleted it.

```
:~$ sudo apt-get remove openvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openvpn' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

:~$ sudo apt-get purge openvpn 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openvpn' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

:~$ openvpn
OpenVPN 2.4.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jun  7 2020
```

I didn't copy-pasted the whole text of last respond to `openvpn` here but it is obvious.

I also couldn't find anthing special at bashrc.

How can I delete openvpn completely in order to install it freshly again?

Comment: How did you install it ?

Comment: I made several attempts to install it. My final method was installing it by extracting it tar.gz files (make, make install on its own folder in my $HOME)

Comment: Since you installed it from source, you need to `sudo make uninstall`. Deleting the files in /usr/local won't do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out to uninstall it.

```
:~$ which openvpn
usr/local/sbin/openvpn
```

I checked usr/local folder and saw a folder a sbin/openvpn. Deleted them.

```
:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/openvpn_as
:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sbin/openvpn
```

Comment: I would go for @heynnema suggestion, it will delete other stuff that may have been installed with the source install.